# Одновременная работа с Room и SQLiteDatabase с одним файлом БД

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

Расширение приложения - новые таблицы и сущности добавляются, старые остаются.
Хочу новые части делать на Room, а старые оставить под SQLiteDatabase.

Поэтому возник вопрос, не будет-ли ошибкой использовать одновременно и Room и SQLiteDatabase?
Не будут конфликтовать?

Comment: Это как java с kotlin месить. Вроде не конфликтует, но запутаться же можно

Comment: @iFr0z, согласен. Но переделывать все  под Room долго. А так новые сущности по идее не должны пересекаться сильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретически возможно, но я бы настоятельно не рекомендовал. Структура файла созданного Room несколько замысловатее и бд разбита на 3 отдельных файла. Это надо уметь такое открывать. Старые и новые сущности не свяжутся в рум, вы не сможете использовать relation и query с участием старых сущностей, адекватно это сделать никак не получится. Вы теряете все прелести Room, делая его использование бессмысленным и плодя пачки костылей для связывания Rom и неRoom сущностей.

Вердикт: если старая и новые базы - совершенно независимы, то используйте два разных файла бд и используйте с одним Room. Если данные связаны - выберите что-то одно